# check if user is signed into twitter

Tags: android, twitter

In my app, the user is allowed to tweet something by pressing a button. I am using the following code:

```
boolean found = false;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Blah blah");
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
final List<?> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
int len = activityList.size();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    final ResolveInfo app = (ResolveInfo) activityList.get(i);
    if ("com.twitter.android.PostActivity".equals(app.activityInfo.name)) {
        found = true;
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.setClassName("com.twitter.android", "com.twitter.android.PostActivity");
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }
}
if(!found)
    showDialog(NO_APP);
```

The code works perfectly but I want to add a feature to it. When the user is not logged into twitter, I want to display a message saying that he is not logged in. The code, as of right now, just directs the user to the sign in page of twitter. How can I disable this and get the desired output? Thanks!!

Comment: that in general is bad approach to the android platform. I suggest you to re-think it. That will only work with the official twitter client and we all know that are several much better more famous clients. Furthermore, why limit on what your user can share? Why not give the normal share dialog and let your user share to whatever social network he/she wants?

Comment: I don't want a general share button because i have different buttons in my app itself to share via SMS, Facebook, email or twitter. Each share method has an individual button

Comment: and my comment/suggestion is to re-think your approach because that's not good one.

Answer (score 1):

For that you can check first that you have the twitterToken and twitterTokenSecret .

Try this way.may it helps :)

```
if(twitterToken!=null && twitterTokenSecret!=null 
    && twitterToken.length()>0 && twitterTokenSecret.length()>0){

  //do your work

}else{
     //show alert dialog

}
```

Comment: I'm not using twitter4j or any other twitter library, so I won't be able to use `twittertoken` or `twitterTokenSecret`

Comment: I think you have to if you want to check whether user is logged in or not

Comment: @user1696863 have you chk your flag value??(as i am assuming that you want to continue your work in the above code.Might be you get the wrong flag value and that's why you don't able to show alert.... )

Comment: @AndroidLearner the flag is to check if the twitter app is installed or not. It does not check if the user is signed in.

Comment: @user1696863 you want to say that you sign in webview and also display the twitter in webview?

Comment: not webview. I'm not transferring the user to the web app. Just the mobile app

Comment: so what you do when you come back after doing successfully login in webview? Display tweet in listview??? I guess...

Comment: I'm not using WebView at all. Only the mobile app

Comment: ohhh... i got it ...sorry for the confusion that i have created around here...btw till now how do you know that whether twitter app is installed in device or not?

Comment: In my code I have used a boolean `found` which does this. If the intent is able to call the `Postactivity` in twitter it opens it. Otherwise if it can't find it, I'm assuming that twitter is not installed

Comment: ohhhhh then found flag will only tell you that whether twitter app is installed or not.. AFAIK, you should use the twitter4j lib to check whether user is alreday logged in or not...

Comment: What if the tokens are invalid? the user will **appear** to be logged in but in actuality, he's not. To make sure the user is REALLY logged in you'll have to request verify_credentials.json.